# query data in business intelligence development studio (BI)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting started with Data Mining for design a website (ASP.NET) that able to show recommendations for customers who have online trading.
Depend on Market Basket (purchasing history), BI show the product that suitable for my recommendation
I have designed all data mining structure and model good and success to query the result in BI

Now, does anybody know how to get result in C#? I want to query to show result on my website but i dont now how to... thanks

Comment: Do you want to show in the form of a report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do want to display in the form of report , you can use SQL Server Reporting Services
(SSRS).

This allows us to display the query data in various formats. It may be Tabular , drill down,

Hiearchial , Pie Charts , graphs etc.

After creating the reports , deploy them  and call from website . There is a control called

ReportViewer which helps in displaying your reports and also export them in Various formats.

Use the below link to Kick start your reporting with SSRS.. Hope this helps..

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/194097/SSRS-Series-Part-I-Various-ways-of-Report-creation

Comment: Exactly! However, in another way, i want to write a web service to deverlop in IOS or ADROID to show recommendation, can you have any suggestion?

Comment: I am unsure about IOS or Android as i have not worked related to mobile technologies, but you we can consume a web service and use that response to create reports and display them. use the below link for reference.http://www.infotoad.com/blog/post/2012/10/01/Reporting-Services-2008-Using-XML-Data-Source-type-and-Querying-a-Web-Service.aspx

Comment: You are seen to confuse between data warehouse and data mining. Data warehouse ofter make report for strategic desion, but in my situation, customer want to get recommendations and my system will having many different query for each customer.